# Bitrise: Certificate / Provisioning Profiles working with Xcode 12 stack but not Xcode 11.7

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, code-signing, bitrise

After renewing our certificates and provisioning profiles last week, our builds systematically fail on Bitrise when using the stack with Xcode 11.7.

However everything works fine on Bitrise with the Xcode 12.2 stack, and locally on my machine with Xcode 11.7.
Unfortunately our project is not Xcode 12 ready yet and we need it to compile with the Xcode 11.7 stack on Bitrise.

Anyone facing the same issue ?

[image: Error messafe]

Comment: first of all can you check your version? : $ bitrise version --format=json

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug of Bitrise need to fix them and yes you should keep using Xcode 12 to deal with this issue. I hope they will release an updated version for this issue soon.

It is a good idea keep in mind some third party dependencies can affect the build after upgrading the Xcode.

Comment: follow releases from here, similar issue
https://github.com/bitrise-io/bitrise/issues/661